# Multiple Conditions in if statement in both "OR" and "AND" operation in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, logic, multiple-conditions

I'm a bit confused with "or" and "and" operations inside "if" statements.
Here, `if(condition_1 || condition_2)` in this operation, when the OR operator checks both of the conditions and its behavior of checking them.
Also `if(condition_1 && condition_2)` in this operation, when the && operator checks both of the conditions and its behavior of checking the conditions.

How "OR" and "AND" operation works in checking two or multiple conditions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unless you are particularly fond of downvotes, don't tag a question with both the C and C++ tags unless it is asking specifically about how the two relate.  Your question title says "C++" — stick with just C++.

Comment: Both the `&&` and `||` operators for built-in types do short-circuit evaluation.  The LHS (left-hand side) is evaluated; if the result can be determined without evaluating the RHS (right-hand side), then the RHS is not evaluated.  If the LHS  of `||` evaluates to true, there is no need to evaluate the RHS.  If the LHS of `&&` evaluates to false, there is no need to evaluate the RHS.  User-defined operators cannot avoid evaluating both the LHS and RHS — do not define such operators.  Any C++ text book should explain this about as simply as I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "OR" operator will return true when one or both of the two conditions is true, and will short circuit if the first item is true.

```
if (condition_1 == true || condition_2 == false) {
   //code will run if either or both of the conditions is true
}
```

The "AND" operator will only work when the both conditions are true and will short circuit if the first operand is false.

```
if (condition_1 == true && condition_2 == true) {
   // code will run when both conditions are true
}
```

Comment: When _at least_ one of the two conditions is true. Or else that would be a XOR gate.

Comment: 1. Does "OR" operation checks the second condition if the first condition results false?
2. Does "AND" operation checks the second condition if the first condition results false?

Comment: @YasinArafat 1. Yes. 2. No.

Comment: @YasinArafat "Short-circuiting" means that the program will stop checking (evaluating expressions) as soon as it can when the outcome is clear.

Answer (score 5):

`||`/`or` and `&&`/`and` do pretty much the same thing in C++ as in spoken language - with one important difference. They short-circuit, meaning, they do not "listen" to the rest if the result can already be deduced.

In

```
if (This or That or Titt or Tatt) {
   make something happen
}
```

it's enough if `This` is *true* and the program will conclude that, yes, it will make something happen.

In

```
if (This and That and Titt and Tatt) {
   make something happen
}
```

it's enough if `This` is *false* and the program will conclude that, no, it will not make something happen.

---

Just as in spoken language, you can make more complicated conditions to allow for something to happen:

```
if ( (This or That) and (Titt or Tatt) ) {
    make something happen
}
```

Meaning

- Either `This` or `That` must be `true`
  and also
- Either `Titt` or `Tatt` must be `true`

The above can be written out as:

```
if      (This and Titt) make something happen
else if (This and Tatt) make something happen
else if (That and Titt) make something happen
else if (That and Tatt) make something happen
else                    nope
```